# Accessing constructor parameters in class method

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm coming from Python and trying to get started with C++, but I seem to be unable to figure out how to access class parameters in C++. I've attached a example Python class, as well as my 3 C++ files.

If this is the Python:

```
class Greeting:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def say_name(self):
        return "Hello, %s" % self.name
```

What would be the C++ equivalent of accessing the `self.name` instance param in the `say_name` method?

Right now this is what I have:

**greeting.hpp**

```
class greeting
{

public:

    greeting(std::string name);
    ~greeting();

    std::string salutation(std::string salutation);

private:

    // Nothing

};
```

**greeting.cpp**

```
#include "greeting.hpp"

greeting::greeting(std::string name, std::string nationality)
{
    std::cout << "greeting class constructed\n";

}

greeting::~greeting()
{

}

std::string greeting::salutation(std::string salutation)
{
    std::string res = salutation + ", " + name;
    return res;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "greeting.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

greeting obj = greeting("Rashad", "American");

std::string word = "Hello";

std::cout << obj.salutation(word) << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Obviously this won't run because the `name` param in the `greeting::salutation` method can't be accessed. So can someone explain how/if I can access C++ constructor params in class methods (similar to the above Python example)?

I'm Running C++ on XCode 8. Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier and productive for you to study some basic C++. Also bear in mind that there may not be a direct equivalent between python and C++.

Comment: It's unconventional in C++ to use the same name for a function as for a variable  (parameter or otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your python code, you have:

```
    self.name = name
```

The object has a member variable called `name` which stores the given input. You need something similar in the C++ class.

```
class greeting
{
  public:

    greeting(std::string name);
    ~greeting();

    std::string salutation(std::string salutation);

 private:

    // Add name as a private member
    std::string name_;

};
```

and make sure the name is stored in the member variable in the constructor.

```
greeting::greeting(std::string name) : name_(name)
{
   std::cout << "greeting class constructed\n";
}
```

You can use the member variable `name_` in other member functions.

```
std::string greeting::salutation(std::string salutation)
{
    std::string res = salutation + ", " + name_;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in .hpp you have **declared** constructor with one parametar.
In .cpp you have **defined** constructor with 2 parametars.

They need to match.

And also, for learning purposes you don't need to separate the class in two files. You don't have to even write the method definitions outside of the class.

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the input @dimm but the question focuses on more of the object aspect answered by @R Sahu, not so much on the syntactical aspect (as I already mentioned that the code didn't run).